# Setting up Visual Studio Online to continuous deployment: There are no projects available

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

I'm following [[this tutorial]](https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/?rnd=1).
I'm currently at point 9.

Instead of choosing "Local git repository", I want to use my git repo from my team project in Visual Studio Online account. Unfortunately, what I see after setting source to Visual Studio Online looks like this:
[image]

> There are no projecs available

Why can't I see my project? How to connect my Visual Studio Online account to Azure?

Comment: Are you able select the `Use an existing project` option?

Comment: @LukkhaCoder: I've finally done this using the old Azure website. On manage.windowsazure.com it worked. But now there is another problem: I linked my VS Online account, but nothing happens :/ Azure says that it build and deploy my site as soon as I check in my code, but I recently commited some changes to git and pushed to server (I can see it on VS Online) but azure do nothing :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Continuous delivery using Visual Studio Online and Git doesn't work. No action after new commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148898/continuous-delivery-using-visual-studio-online-and-git-doesnt-work-no-action-a)

Comment: It seems to me that the integration is terrible now. I have tried to follow all the steps in various How-to with multiple power shell scripts and what not and they all just fail to work. According to some videos the integration with GitHub is just few clicks, but VSO is a complete disaster (especially with ASP.NET 5), which is hard to explain...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try following these steps to link your Visual Studio Online account with your Azure accounts?
[How to Link Existing Visual Studio Online with Windows Azure](http://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/01/06/how-to-link-existing-visual-studio-online-with-windows-azure/)

Another option as the comment to the question pointed out is to use the [old Azure portal](http://manage.windowsazure.com)

Answer (score 0):

After some research it seems that you have to do the linking in the new portal (I did the linking in the old, but that did not seem to help). It is available in the new portal under "Visual Studio Online accounts", after that "Visual Studio Online team projects" should show your projects.

My build of ASP.NET 5 still fails with some errors, but it seem at least the connection was set up...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and selecting via "Team Services Accounts" from portal -> Browse menu, and clicking on the link button fixed the issue. Now I can see my existing VS online projects and deployment source.