# Continuous delivery using Visual Studio Online and Git doesn't work. No action after new commit

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to publish to the internet my Node.js web application. Relating to [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/), I need to set up "continuous deployment" from git repository.

I connected my Visual Studio Online account (where I keep my application) to Azure. Now, it looks like this:
[image]

My project should have been built and deployed to Azure on my next check-in. So I commited some small change and pushed it to Visual Studio Online. I can see on VSOnline website that the change in git repo is commited to the master branch.

So everything seems to be fine, but Azure doesn't respond :/ It still tells me to do some check-in. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does anything show up in the deployment history when you do a check in?

Answer (score 2):

The Visual Studio Online workflow currently only supports .NET by default. For a Node.js application, you would have to modify the Build Template to remove the .NET build then add an activity to run NPM. As long as everything is placed in the drop folder for WebDeploy to bundle the package, the deployment should go fine.